# PHP Method will echo/print_r results but will not return them

Tags: php

This method seems to always return false even though I can print_r the results before the return statement, I always get false. Method in question....

```
    public static function getGroupOptions($pid=0, $ogid=0) {

        if($data = self::getOptionsData($pid, $ogid)) {
            $Options = array();
            Load::Object('ProductOption');
            foreach($data as $key => $rec) {
                $Option = new ProductOptionObject;
                $Option->Populate($rec);
                array_push($Options, $Option);

            }

            //echo "<pre>";print_r($Options);echo "</pre>";die;  
            return $Options;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

print_r dumps the array of ProductOptionObject's with the correct data no problems.

This is calling line...

```
            $Options = ProductOptionFactory::getGroupOptions($this->pId, $this->getBean('ogId'));
            //echo gettype($Options); echo $Options === false ? "FALSE" : "NOT FALSE"; die;
```

debug line always prints 'Boolean FALSE'.

Using: PHP 5.3.14 / Apache2 2.2.8 / CentOS 5.8

Comment: Is there any typo in your _actual_ code? Your posted code seems OK.

Comment: You must be missing something. Your code is okay

Comment: no, i've been over it so many times, i think i may have just discovered something though, some cached data with a huuuuge stack trace attached, possibly causing php internal error and skipping the first return statement?? PHP throws no errors though and there is nothing in the logs

Comment: Is there something which is calling this function recursively? Are you inside some sort of loop? I can't see anything wrong with the code you've posted, so I'm just throwing ideas in.

Comment: its not recursive but it is called from a loop, as in it calls it for each ObjectGroupObject (there are 3 on this page) however at present i've asked it to die after the first call.

Comment: and there is no further call to getGroupOptions from within getOptionsData? I only ask because this type of problem "smells" to me like possible accidental recursion.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some typo in your actual code. Your code seems to be okay. Try debugging the code and you get to know where you have missed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **static** instead of **self** ex:

```
self::getOptionsData($pid, $ogid);

/** rather use */ 

static:getOptionsData($pid, $ogid);
```

But this works perfectly fine regardless:

```
php> class A {
 ...    public static function getOpt() {
 ...       return array(1,2,3);
 ...    }
 ...    public static function getGrpOpt() {
 ...       if (false != $opt = self::getOpt()) {
 ...          return $opt;
 ...       }
 ...       return false;
 ...    }
 ... }

php> var_export(A::getGrpOpt())
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
)
```

So I am lead to believe that the problem is with the getOptionsData function you are not showing us.

It would also help if you show how you manage to get the internal debug to print as I am sure that it will then return $Options as instructed, it has no other choice.

Use var_dump or var_export to easily see false values printed while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to capture the output of print_r, use the return parameter:

```
print("<pre>" . print_r($res, true) . "</pre>");
```